# Retrifit and simpleXMLConverter

Tags: android, retrofit

I've been trying to use Retrofit with an API which works with XML. I also notice that retrofit have an XML Converter called SimpleXmlConverter here:

https://github.com/mobile-professionals/retrofit-simplexmlconverter

But when I tried to use it, got this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14844
retrofit.RetrofitError: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:409)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:284)
        at com.aaaa.common.$Proxy0.configs(Native Method)
        at com.aaaa.common.DemoAPI.getContributos(DemoAPI.java:47)
        at com.aaaa.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
        at retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter.fromBody(SimpleXMLConverter.java:38)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:394)
```

```
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:284)
            at com.aaaa.common.$Proxy0.configs(Native Method)
            at com.aaaa.common.DemoAPI.getContributos(DemoAPI.java:47)
            at com.aaaa.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForType cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
            at retrofit.converter.SimpleXMLConverter.fromBody(SimpleXMLConverter.java:36)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:394)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:284)
            at com.aaaa.common.$Proxy0.configs(Native Method)
            at com.aaaa.common.DemoAPI.getContributos(DemoAPI.java:47)
            at com.aaaa.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'm making a sample App so I'm just trying to be simple with my code:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            //.setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .setServer(API_URL)
            .setConverter(new SimpleXMLConverter())
            .build();
```

And

```
static class Config {
    String name;
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
}

interface Demo {
    @GET("/{user}/api/config")
    List<Config> configs (
            @Path("user") String owner
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the "SimpleXmlConverter" class that belongs to the retrofit-simplexmlconverter library. Instead you're using the "SimpleXMLConverter" class (see uppercase "XML") that is part of retrofit itself since a while. I'd advise you to go with the official one as this is unit tested and under more active development.
I created the retrofit-simplexmlconverter lib when there was no xml converter for retrofit yet.

Unfortunately I don't see the reason for your problem at first sight. The implementation of the converter classes should be similar. So concerning your problem I think it shouldn't make a difference which one you use. If I were you I'd step in with a debugger to get a clue about what's causing the ClassCastException.

Comment: Thank you for reply Sebastian, I've been trying with your library too but nothing.. as you said, the problem continues.

Comment: I have 2 open possibilities now:

* I Saw the XML Header is not "conventional":
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?><config> <nombre>Juego de preguntas</nombre> <intentos>3</intentos> <puntosIncrementales>10</puntosIncrementales></config>

* Gradle import in Android Studio needs to exclude some libraries:
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }

Do you think any of this can cause the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. But I notice that your field names in the Config class do not match your xml element names. And I also think you need some annotations. See here in the SimpleXML documentation: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

Looks like Inner Classes can't be instantiated in the same way than normal classes by reflect, they need to be instantiated by a Constructor, so.. SimpleXMLconverter not works with inner classes like mine:

```
static class Config {
    String name;
    int firstInt;
    int secondInt;
}
```

I just made a new folder "Models" with that classes and works perfect! ;)

Really thanks to @Sebastian Engel for teach me and show me how it to solve it.